# pgfplots: y axis arrow pointing down

Tags: pgfplots, arrows, axis

How can I make the y axis arrow positioned in the other end of the axis and pointing down?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,systeme,mathtools} 
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  legend pos=outer north east,
  legend cell align={left},
  grid, grid style=dashed,
  xmax=1.1,xmin=0,
  ymin=-1.2,ymax=0,
  ytick={-1.1,-1,-0.9,-0.8,-0.7,-0.6,-0.5,-0.4,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1},
  xtick={0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1},
  extra y ticks={0},            % <---
  extra x ticks={0},            % <---
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,                   % <---
  xlabel={$x_2$},ylabel={$V_m$}, 
  x label style={at={(1,1)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,0)},below},
               ]
  \addplot[mark=*,scatter,only marks]
    coordinates {
    (0.0281,-0.115)(0.0435,-0.157)(0.0587,-0.262)(0.0896,-0.359)(0.1180,-0.500)(0.1524,-0.631)(0.3107,-0.894)(1,0)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend cell align={left},
    hide axis,
    ymin=-1.2,ymax=0,
    xmax=1.1,xmin=0,
    domain=0:1,
    samples=2000,
    set layers,
    ]
   \addplot [cyan,smooth,thick,dashed] {4.3292*x*x - 4.3116*x - 0.0153};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Simply add   `y axis line style={stealth-}` at the end of your `axis` options.

See `pgfplots` manual p271 §4.9. Axis description (in v1.15)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  legend pos=outer north east,
  legend cell align={left},
  grid, grid style=dashed,
  xmax=1.1,xmin=0,
  ymin=-1.2,ymax=0,
  ytick={-1.1,-1,-0.9,-0.8,-0.7,-0.6,-0.5,-0.4,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1},
  xtick={0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1},
  extra y ticks={0},            % <---
  extra x ticks={0},            % <---
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,                   % <---
  xlabel={$x_2$},ylabel={$V_m$}, 
  x label style={at={(1,1)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,-1)},above},
  y axis line style={stealth-},   % <====== right here !
               ]
  \addplot[mark=*,scatter,only marks]
    coordinates {
    (0.0281,-0.115)(0.0435,-0.157)(0.0587,-0.262)(0.0896,-0.359)(0.1180,-0.500)(0.1524,-0.631)(0.3107,-0.894)(1,0)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend cell align={left},
    hide axis,
    ymin=-1.2,ymax=0,
    xmax=1.1,xmin=0,
    domain=0:1,
    samples=2000,
    set layers,
    ]
   \addplot [cyan,smooth,thick,dashed] {4.3292*x*x - 4.3116*x - 0.0153};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Figure]

Comment: Very well! Another simple simple question: What is the key to displaying the x ticks above the axis? Thank you!

Comment: You can start with adding `x tick label style={anchor=south,yshift=1ex}` to your options