# 'Smarter' axis arrows in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

For any common x>0, y>0 function the standard axis arrow locations in a pgfplot are great

[image]

Unfortunately, for more negative functions (domain or range), the arrows are a bit funny (red = what I want).

[image]
[image]
[image]

It does seem possible to manually set the arrows right as in [pgfplots: y axis arrow pointing down](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497202/pgfplots-y-axis-arrow-pointing-down)

However what would be fantastic is if it were possible to have te plot use the right arrows *automaticly*!

I'm thinking some sort of logic such as:

- If x-axis goes >0 use right arrow
- If x-axis goes <0 use left arrow
- If y-axis goes >0 use top arrow
- If y-axis goes <0 use bottom arrow

However I have no clue how this might be done, would anyone be willing to help?

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfplotsset{
    no marks,axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={-{Latex[length=4mm]}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
            \addplot+{x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about `axis lines*=middle`, i.e. adding a `*`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything for me

Comment: Really? Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{
    no marks,axis lines*=middle,
    inner axis line style={-{Latex[length=4mm]}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
            \addplot+{-x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}`

Comment: I see this https://i.ibb.co/dbpCdZ0/image.png

Comment: Yes. It is not precisely what you suggest but does not have the problems you are mentioning either.

Comment: Ah. I see, the arrow extends over the axis instead of 'pointing to' it. You're right, that is an improvement, I just didn't notice at first because it wasn't what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does what you suggest, I think. The `iaxis` style looks whether the origin is left/right/above/below of the axis boundaries, and adds the arrows accordingly.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}

\pgfplotsset{no marks,
    iaxis/.style={,axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={-},clip mode=individual,execute at end axis={
    \path[tips=proper] let \p1=($(rel axis cs:1,1)-(axis cs:0,0)$),
     \p2=($(axis cs:0,0)-(rel axis cs:0,0)$)
     in %\pgfextra{\typeout{\x1,\x2,\y1,\y2}}
     \ifdim\x1>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=4mm]}] ({rel axis cs:1,0} |- {axis cs:0,0})
     \fi
     \ifdim\x2>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=4mm]}] ({rel axis cs:0,0} |- {axis cs:0,0})
     \fi
     \ifdim\y1>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=4mm]}] ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:0,0})
     \fi
     \ifdim\y2>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=4mm]}] ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:0,0})
     \fi;
    }},
    every axis/.append style=iaxis
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
        \addplot+{x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
        \addplot+{-x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-1:0]
        \addplot+{x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-1:0]
        \addplot+{-x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-1:1]
        \addplot+{-x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with overshooting arrows (which alter the dimensions of the axis objects).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}

\pgfplotsset{no marks,
    iaxis/.style={axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={-},clip mode=individual,execute at end axis={
    \path[tips=proper] let \p1=($(rel axis cs:1,1)-(axis cs:0,0)$),
     \p2=($(axis cs:0,0)-(rel axis cs:0,0)$)
     in %\pgfextra{\typeout{\x1,\x2,\y1,\y2}}
     \ifdim\x1>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=4mm]}] 
      ($({rel axis cs:1,0} |- {axis cs:0,0})+($(4mm,0)-(0,0)$)$)
     \fi
     \ifdim\x2>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=4mm]}] 
      ($({rel axis cs:0,0} |- {axis cs:0,0})+($(-4mm,0)-(0,0)$)$)
     \fi
     \ifdim\y1>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=4mm]}] 
      ($({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:0,0})+($(0,4mm)-(0,0)$)$)
     \fi
     \ifdim\y2>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=4mm]}] 
      ($({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:0,0})+($(0,-4mm)-(0,0)$)$)
     \fi;
    }},
    every axis/.append style=iaxis
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
        \addplot+{x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
        \addplot+{-x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-1:0]
        \addplot+{x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-1:0]
        \addplot+{-x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-1:1]
        \addplot+{-x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're on fire! Thanks for being so handy. This is great, the only case it doesn't work for is `...[domain=-1:1] \addplot+{x}...`

Comment: Also one little thing, not sure if I should put this in a separate question (not sure if solution would transfer), but do you know any good way of preventing the arrowheads and tick marks from overlapping? (see https://i.ibb.co/Cn1Q6BT/image.png)

Comment: @tecosaur As for the first comment, there was a typo that I fixed. As for the second one, I do not know how to fix this in general.

Comment: Would it be possible to extend the arrow position by the length of the arrow? That way they should never overlap.

Comment: @tecosaur Yes, but this would also change the dimensions of the axis, wouldn't it?

Comment: Slightly, but I don't think that's a big issue — or is there something I'm missing? (btw, the arrows I actually use are just the default length/size)

Comment: @tecosaur You are right, as long as one warns the user that this is what's happening it might be OK. I added this option.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again for all the help you've been giving me. My custom class now produces better graphs because of you! I would like to not bother the community as much but there's a lot I've yet to get a handle on.

Comment: @tecosaur You are welcome and you are not "bothering" others. Participating here is a voluntary act.

Comment: I'm afraid I have another issue to bother you with. Try this: `\begin{axis}[domain=0:2,ymax=9.9] \addplot+{1/(e*x^2))}; \end{axis}`. I see https://i.ibb.co/GW1fryX/image.png

Comment: @tecosaur This has to do with how pgfplots deals with unbounded coordinates. It is next-to-impossible to program all cases into a style. You can solve the issue by saying `\begin{axis}[domain=0:2,xmin=0,ymin=0,ymax=9.9] 
\addplot+{1/(e*x^2))}; 
\end{axis}`.

Comment: That's unfortunate. So there's no good way to get the 'graph origin' coordinate?

Comment: @tecosaur According to the manual this is `rel axis cs:0,0`, but, as you see, in case of singularities there are corrections. `current axis.south west` has the same issue. Dealing with those singularities is nontrivial, and what pgfplots accomplishes is a lot. If you are asking a question specifically on that, you may get a different opinion.