# disable tick at end of axis

Tags: pgfplots

#### Intro

Thanks to a lot of help from *Schrödinger's cat* in ['Smarter' axis arrows in pgfplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510205/smarter-axis-arrows-in-pgfplot)
I now have some fancy arrows at the end of the plots. The thing is, since my arrows now line up perfectly with the end of the plot, any tick mark there is now somewhat redundant.

#### Problem

What I'd like to do is not draw axis ticks that happen to lie at the very end of the axis, as they're now a bit redundant.

#### Example

[image: example]

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
\pgfplotsset{
    no marks,
    minor x tick num=1,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    every x tick/.style={thick},
    every y tick/.style={thick},
    tick align=outside,
    axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={-},clip mode=individual,execute at end axis={
    \path[tips=proper] let \p1=($(rel axis cs:1,1)-(axis cs:0,0)$),
     \p2=($(axis cs:0,0)-(rel axis cs:0,0)$)
     in %\pgfextra{\typeout{\x1,\x2,\y1,\y2}}
     \ifdim\x1>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=1.5mm]}]
      ($({rel axis cs:1,0} |- {axis cs:0,0})+($(1.5mm,0)-(0,0)$)$)
     \fi
     \ifdim\x2>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=1.5mm]}]
      ($({rel axis cs:0,0} |- {axis cs:0,0})+($(-1.5mm,0)-(0,0)$)$)
     \fi
     \ifdim\y1>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=1.5mm]}]
      ($({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:0,0})+($(0,1.5mm)-(0,0)$)$)
     \fi
     \ifdim\y2>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=1.5mm]}]
      ($({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:0,0})+($(0,-1.5mm)-(0,0)$)$)
     \fi;
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
        \addplot+[]{x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### NB

This may not look like much, but it's a bigger deal with the *full* set of options that I'm using:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can cheat and set the `xtick placement tolerance` and `ytick placement tolerance` to negative values.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
\pgfplotsset{xtick placement tolerance=-1mm,ytick placement tolerance=-1mm,
    no marks,
    minor x tick num=1,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    every x tick/.style={thick},
    every y tick/.style={thick},
    tick align=outside,
    axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={-},clip mode=individual,execute at end axis={
    \path[tips=proper] let \p1=($(rel axis cs:1,1)-(axis cs:0,0)$),
     \p2=($(axis cs:0,0)-(rel axis cs:0,0)$)
     in %\pgfextra{\typeout{\x1,\x2,\y1,\y2}}
     \ifdim\x1>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=1.5mm]}]
      ($({rel axis cs:1,0} |- {axis cs:0,0})+($(1.5mm,0)-(0,0)$)$)
     \fi
     \ifdim\x2>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=1.5mm]}]
      ($({rel axis cs:0,0} |- {axis cs:0,0})+($(-1.5mm,0)-(0,0)$)$)
     \fi
     \ifdim\y1>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=1.5mm]}]
      ($({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:0,0})+($(0,1.5mm)-(0,0)$)$)
     \fi
     \ifdim\y2>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=1.5mm]}]
      ($({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:0,0})+($(0,-1.5mm)-(0,0)$)$)
     \fi;
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
        \addplot+[]{x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This trick allows you to avoid the overshoot problem discussed under your previous question.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}

\pgfplotsset{xtick placement tolerance=-2mm,ytick placement tolerance=-2mm,
    no marks,
    minor x tick num=1,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    every x tick/.style={thick},
    every y tick/.style={thick},
    tick align=outside,
    axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={-},clip mode=individual,execute at end axis={
    \path[tips=proper] let \p1=($(rel axis cs:1,1)-(axis cs:0,0)$),
     \p2=($(axis cs:0,0)-(rel axis cs:0,0)$)
     in %\pgfextra{\typeout{\x1,\x2,\y1,\y2}}
     \ifdim\x1>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=1.5mm]}] ({rel axis cs:1,0} |- {axis cs:0,0})
     \fi
     \ifdim\x2>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=1.5mm]}] ({rel axis cs:0,0} |- {axis cs:0,0})
     \fi
     \ifdim\y1>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=1.5mm]}] ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:0,0})
     \fi
     \ifdim\y2>0pt
      (axis cs:0,0) edge[-{Latex[length=1.5mm]}] ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:0,0})
     \fi;
    }}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
        \addplot+{x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
        \addplot+{-x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-1:0]
        \addplot+{x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-1:0]
        \addplot+{-x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-1:1]
        \addplot+{-x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Sneaky, I like it. Two issues for me though: for some charts it makes zero appear on the axis (e.g. if `domain=-1:1` is used) which doesn't look too good. Also I'd rather keep the number, just remove the mark.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I made that second part clear in my original question.

Comment: @tecosaur Looking at the complexity of `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsticks.code.tex` I feel there may not be a very simple trick that deals with all of these things, including the zeros.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for giving this a shot!